# Prohibit MySQL from using full table scan on a query

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization

Is there any way I can prohibit MySQL from performing a full table scan when the result was not found using indexes?

For example this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE (X BETWEEN a.B AND a.C) 
ORDER BY a.B DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Is only efficient if X satisfies the condition and there is at least 1 row returned, but if the condition cannot be satisfied by any data in the table, full scan will be performed, which can be very costly.

I don't want to optimize this particular query, it is just an example.

EXPLAIN on this query with X in or outside of range:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra
1 SIMPLE a range long_ip  long_ip 8 \N 116183 100.00 Using where
```

STATUS VARIABLE show much better information. For X outside of range:

```
Handler_read_prev 84181
Key_read_requests 11047
```

In range:

```
Handler_read_key 1
Key_read_requests 12
```

If only there was a way to prevent Handler_read_prev from ever growing past 1.

**UPDATE.** I can't accept my own answer, because it doesn't really answer the question (HANDLER is a great feature, though). It seems to me that there is no general way to prevent MySQL from doing a full scan. Although, simple conditions like key='X' will be considered as "impossible where", more complex things like BETWEEN will not.

Comment: I assume you have an index on the pair (B, C), not each column individually, right? Maybe the index statistics are wrong, have you tried to run `ANALYZE` on the table?

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean "index statistics are wrong"? I'm not trying to optimize this query, I'm just asking if there is any way to prohibit MySQL from performing a full table scan.

Comment: The query optimizer relies on data statistics. It determines costs based on the statistics and chooses the most optimal way to go. If the statistics are off, the cost estimates will be wrong, it won't use the best way to get the data. I'm saying this only because on a large table with freshly created index it uses the index even if the query returns no results.

Comment: @HeavyWave - Mea culpa maxima - never post an answer in a hurry when about to go out the door!

Comment: Could you post your table and index definitions, and the EXPLAIN output for the query?

Comment: I've updated the post. Although, I am NOT looking to optimize this particular query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I came up with in the end:

```
HANDLER a OPEN;
HANDLER a READ BC <= (X);
HANDLER a CLOSE;
```

BC is the name of key (B,C). If we order the table by B DESC, then the result is guranteed to be equal to

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE (X BETWEEN a.B AND a.C) 
ORDER BY a.B DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

Now if X is not in the range of the table a, we just have to check that a.C is greater than X, if it's not, than X is definitely outside of the range and we don't need to look any further.

This is not very elegant though, and you will have to resort the table on each insert or update.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a "fully covered" subquery that only uses data that is available in indexes.  Based on the returned primary key, you can look up the rows in the master table.

The following query is fully covered by indexes on (id), (B,id), and (C,id):

```
select *
from a
where id in (
    select id
    from a 
    where x <= C
    and id in (
        select id
        from a
        where B <= X 
    )
)
limit 1
```

Each SELECT uses one index: the innermost the index on (B,id); the middle SELECT uses the index on (C,id), and the outer SELECT uses the primary key.

Comment: LIMIT and IN are not supported, besides this query will be terribly slow and I don't see how my query is not covered by indexes. In fact, it is and the question was, how to stop MySQL when it hasn't found the answer in indexes (which it should be doing in the first place).

Comment: You're right about limit in a subquery, moved it to the outer query.  My proposed query will not do a table scan when no results are found, because the middle select will be empty.  It should be pretty fast, have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, it runs for more than a second on 10 mb table. The 2 inner queries return thousands of rows.

Comment: If you created the indexes, it should be as fast as it gets.  If there are additional constraints you can do far better.  For example, if B and C never overlap between rows, you can search for the first B below X.  That would be truly fast.

Comment: Have you tried it? It is very slow with any indexes on MySQL 5.